# Object with Timer is not firing off its handlers, thread is closing instead

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am pretty sure I am missing something very obvious here, but I have an object which just needs to run some code every three seconds. I define a Timer, I tell it what to do and I set it going.

The issue is that the events don't fire. I have found an ugly hack to *make* them fire, but that killed the main window. That `while (true) ;` keeps the object from disappearing, but the main window disappears.

I am sure I should know the answer, but it's just not clicking for me...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ParseLog logParser;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            logParser = new ParseLog();
        }
    }

    class ParseLog
    {
        public string[] updatedFiles;

        public ParseLog()
        {
            AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            Console.WriteLine("{0:h:mm:ss.fff} Creating timer.\n",
                              DateTime.Now);

            // Create a timer that invokes CheckFile every 3 seconds
            Timer stateTimer = new Timer(CheckFile, autoEvent, 0, 3000);

//            while (true) ;
        }

        public void CheckFile(Object stateInfo)
        {
            AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Checking files.",
                DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.fff"));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your piece of code is not a good design pattern. You should promote your local timer variable to a class-level member field and make sure to dispose it when you're done. If you leave it in the constructor (as a local variable), the GarbageCollector might claim it anytime; that's why it fires in the beginning and ceases at some point.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ParseLog logParser;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        logParser = new ParseLog();
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        logParser.Dispose();
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}

class ParseLog : IDisposable
{
    public string[] updatedFiles;
    readonly Timer stateTimer;

    public ParseLog()
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        Console.WriteLine("{0:h:mm:ss.fff} Creating timer.\n",
                            DateTime.Now);

        // Create a timer that invokes CheckFile every 3 seconds
        stateTimer = new Timer(CheckFile, autoEvent, 0, 3000);
    }

    public void CheckFile(Object stateInfo)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Checking files.",
            DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.fff"));

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        stateTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AnthonyHJ and as additional note your `while(true);` trick will work only in `Debug` but will fail in `Release`. In Release there is some optimization saying to GC that `stateTimer` is not in use anymore and can be collected even so it's still in scope of the method.

Comment: Please vote up useful answers so it may help others with similar problems in the future.